# Laravel searchy to search through relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have implemented this library as a full text search.

https://github.com/TomLingham/Laravel-Searchy

Do anyone know how to search through relationship table.

for eg:

Application model store status as integer and reference to Status model for the name.

```
application_status = 1
```

In Status Model:

```
id:Name
1:Approve
2:Reject
```

Sample Code:

```
Searchy::applications('status')->query('Approve')->get();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean by doing joins? Or using Eloquent relations and whereHas?

Comment: Hi @fubar, i edited my question